# NSDatePicker timezone weirdness

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nstimezone, nsdatepicker

I have an NSDatePicker in my nib file.  In code, I set it's timezone to be the GMT calendar's timezone:

```
[datePicker setTimeZone:[calendar timeZone]];
```

I only really care about the time (hours, minutes) on the datepicker which I populate programmatically:

```
NSDate *anyDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:anyDate];
        [components setHour:hours];
        [components setMinute:minutes];
        NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        [datePicker setDateValue:newDate];
```

This correctly has the desired effect of setting the date pickers time to the time I want.  So if hours is 8 and minutes is 30, the date picker shows 8:30.  However, if I type an 8 into the hour field of the date picker it displays as a 3.  Something weird is going on with timezones somewhere but I'm not sure where...

Comment: Do you have a date formatter attached to the date picker?

Answer (score 8):

Seems like I'm not the first person to stumble across this issue.  The solution, for those who are interested, I found here http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/305254-nsdatepicker-weirdness-with-time.html.  Apparently if you set the timezone of a date picker but not the calendar, you get this issue.  The resolution is this:

```
[datePicker setTimeZone:[calendar timeZone]];
[datePicker setCalendar:calendar];
```

Comment: Just helped me solve the same problem - thanks for posting your findings!

Comment: Surely simpler and more correct to set the date picker's `locale` to the current locale.